# How to get the shipping address by order ID?

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping-address, service-contract

How to get the correct shipping address for an order ID? I am using `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` to get the order information by order ID, but there are no methods for getting the shipping address, despite a lot of people on the internet claiming otherwise.

I considered using `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderAddressRepositoryInterface`, and I am able to return *a* shipping address, but it is not the correct one.

It took me a long time to understand why the `get()` method from `OrderAddressRepositoryInterface` wasn't returning the right data when passing the same `$orderId` parameter as in `OrderRepositoryInterface`, but then I found out that Magento inserts two entries in the `sales_order_address` table for each entry in the `sales_order` table - for some reason.
The address row from `sales_order_address` is then relationally matched with the right order in the `sales_order` table by the column `shipping_address_id` in the `sales_order` table, which corresponds to the `entity_id` in the `sales_order_address` table.

It would be easy to use `OrderAddressRepositoryInterface` if there was a `getShippingAddressId()` method declared in `OrderRepositoryInterface`, but there is none!

So how can I find/match the right shipping address with a particular order ID? I would love to hear suggestions for how to use the service layer to solve this, and not the persistence or domain layers.

Comment: Did you try getList? get($id) where $id is the entity_id column of sales_order_address table.

Comment: @SohelRana: But the problem is that there are exactly two rows with two different entity_id in the sales_order_address table that have the same parent_id. So using getList($orderId) will return a list of two addresses, but I only need one.

Comment: Nope, Check my answer that is what I want to refer you.

Answer (score 0):

***Check the following way:***

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository $addressRepository */
$addressRepository = $obj->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository');

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $obj->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
$searchCriteriaBuilder
    ->addFilter('parent_id', '3')
    ->addFilter('address_type', 'shipping');
$address = $addressRepository
    ->getList($searchCriteriaBuilder->create());
```

**Don't use the object manager, I used it for a quick check. Use DI instead.**

Answer (score 0):

When you say you got the wrong shipping address - do you mean you got billing address?

As a quick test, I can retrieve correct shipping address from order repository, but it's a bit convoluted.

1. You call **getExtensionAttributes** which returns \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionInterface
2. then call **getShippingAssignments** which returns \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface
3. then loop assignment and call **getShipping** which returns \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingInterface

4. call **getAddress** which returns \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface
5. from there, you can get the individual shipping lines

[image: shipping address code]
(sorry code kept getting mangled when I tried pasting)